# I want to change the GifImageView location on Android

Tags: android, imageview, location, tgifimage

```
package com.bariskarapelit.stajprojesi_1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import com.twilio.video.CameraCapturer;
import com.twilio.video.LocalVideoTrack;
import com.twilio.video.VideoTextureView;

import pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView;
import android.view.MotionEvent.*;
import static androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.getX;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    ImageButton button,button1,button2;
    GridLayout gridLayout;
    ImageView circle,dislike,like;
    VideoView videoView;
    String videoPath;
    VideoTextureView  videoTextureView;
    Uri uri;
    GifImageView gifImageView;
    MotionEvent event;
    private LayoutParams layoutParams;
    int windowwidth;
    int windowheight;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button= findViewById(R.id.circle);
        button1=findViewById(R.id.dislike);
        button2=findViewById(R.id.like);



        circle=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        dislike=findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        like=findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        gifImageView= findViewById(R.id.gift);



        circle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        dislike.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        like.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //videoView=findViewById(R.id.video_view_top_right);
        //Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.video);
        //videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        gifImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {


                LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) gifImageView.getLayoutParams();
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                        if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                            x_cord = windowwidth;
                        }
                        if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                            y_cord = windowheight;
                        }

                        layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 75;

                        gifImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }


                return true;
            }
        });






        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Circle",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                gifImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.daire);
            }
        });
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Dislike",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                gifImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dislike);

            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Like",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                gifImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);

            }
        });





    }
}
```

I want to change the GifImageView location on Android. By taking the position of the point at which the User has woven into the screen with the OnTouchListener method.  I want to use this location in GifImageView relocation. Can you help me?

```
gifImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    
    
                    LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) gifImageView.getLayoutParams();
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                            int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
    
                            if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                                x_cord = windowwidth;
                            }
                            if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                                y_cord = windowheight;
                            }
    
                            layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                            layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
    
                            gifImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
    
    
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

I tried to change places using the above code, but this error was included:

```
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
        at com.bariskarapelit.stajprojesi_1.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:79)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:13469)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2845)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2845)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2845)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2845)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:742)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1880)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3494)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:700)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6175)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5953)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5402)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5455)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5421)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5580)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5429)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5637)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5402)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5455)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5421)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5429)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5402)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8467)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8387)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8340)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8582)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:198)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.twilio.video.VideoTextureView
        android:id="@+id/video_view_top_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/gift"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="492dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="168dp"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="244dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/launch1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="244dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/launch2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="428dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/launch3" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/launch1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/dislike"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.574"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dislike"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/launch2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.499"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"></ImageButton>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/like"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/launch3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.447"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dislike"></ImageButton>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selectedImage = R.drawable.ic_dislike3;